# JQuery fadeIn one, fadeOut multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have a function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showt").click(function(){
    $(".t").fadeIn("fast");
  });
  $("#showt").click(function(){
    $(".m").fadeOut(0);
  });
  $("#showt").click(function(){
    $(".a").fadeOut(0);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showm").click(function(){
    $(".m").fadeIn("fast");
  });
  $("#showm").click(function(){
    $(".t").fadeOut(0);
  });
  $("#showm").click(function(){
    $(".a").fadeOut(0);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showa").click(function(){
    $(".a").fadeIn("fast");
  });
  $("#showa").click(function(){
    $(".t").fadeOut(0);
  });
  $("#showa").click(function(){
    $(".m").fadeOut(0);
  });
});
```

So on a click of a link with a certain ID it shows one, but hides other blocks, everything works perfectly but I'm just interested is there a way to reduce the function's code?

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="tag" id="showt">ttt</a>
<a href="#" class="tag" id="showm">mmm</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag" id="showa">aaa</a>          

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="t">
        Ttt
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        Mmm
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        Aaa
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="t">
        Ttt
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        Mmm
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        Aaa
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4"></div>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML.

Comment: HTML added. And the display of these DIVs is set to none in CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, put in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can considerably consolidate your code by using custom attributes; I chose the name `show-class` to denote the class the link wants to show.  If you plan to add more classes than just `.t`, `.m`, and `.a` you could add a secondary class that all of them (`.t, .m, .a`) have in common, and fade that out.  Additionally, you can use the `.hide()` function to make your code a little simpler (rather than `.fadeOut(0)`).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".showStuff").click(function (){
    $(".t, .m, .a").hide();
    $("." + $(this).attr("show-class")).fadeIn("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tag showStuff" show-class="t">ttt</a>
<a href="#" class="tag showStuff" show-class="m">mmm</a> 
<a href="#" class="tag showStuff" show-class="a">aaa</a>          

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="t">
        Ttt
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        Mmm
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        Aaa
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="t">
        Ttt
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        Mmm
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        Aaa
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Working fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could use toggle() to toggle the current state. 
[here is the link for api](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Also to reduce, you can make a function which will work as callback function for similar work. Like

> $('.bar').click(callback);